# How to inject same service with different alias in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony6

I'm not sure if the question in the title is the right one so I will try to explain my problem as simply as I can:

I'm using the [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/index.md) with this configuration:

```
# Read the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/setup.md
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        articles:
            index_name: 'articles'
            persistence:
                # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\Site\FArticle\FArticleProp
                provider: ~
                finder: ~
```

To query my `articles` index I do it like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder;

class FArticleService
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly TransformedFinder $finder,
    )
    {
    }

    public function query(array $query, int $page, int $size)
    {
        $results = $this->finder->createRawPaginatorAdapter($query)->getResults(($page * $size) - $size, $size);
    }
}
```

But I got error:

```
In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 51:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  Cannot autowire service "App\Service\FArticleService": argument "$finder" of method "__construct()" references class "FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "fos_elastica.finder.articles" service.
```

So I fix it with:

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
  #...
  FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder:
    alias: fos_elastica.finder.articles
    public: true
```

And everything works fine.

But now I'm adding a second index `fdocentetes`:

```yaml
# Read the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/setup.md
fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
  indexes:
    articles:
      index_name: 'articles'
      persistence:
        # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
        driver: orm
        model: App\Entity\Site\FArticle\FArticleProp
        provider: ~
        finder: ~
    fdocentetes:
      index_name: 'fdocentetes'
      persistence:
        # the driver can be orm, mongodb or phpcr
        driver: orm
        model: App\Entity\Sage\FDocentete
        provider: ~
        finder: ~
```

But now I don't know how to query on the `fdocentetes` index as `TransformedFinder` has the alias `fos_elastica.finder.articles` so if I create another service `FDocenteteService`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder;

class FDocenteteService
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly TransformedFinder $finder,
    )
    {
    }

    public function query(array $query, int $page, int $size)
    {
        // this will query on the index articles while I want to query on index fdocentetes
        $results = $this->finder->createRawPaginatorAdapter($query)->getResults(($page * $size) - $size, $size);
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to fix this ?

```
$ php bin/console debug:container | grep fos_elastica.finder
  FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder      alias for "fos_elastica.finder.articles"
  fos_elastica.finder                              FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder
  fos_elastica.finder.articles                     FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder
  fos_elastica.finder.fdocentetes                  FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder
```

```
$ php bin/console debug:autowiring | grep fos_elastica.finder
 FOS\ElasticaBundle\Finder\TransformedFinder (fos_elastica.finder.articles)
```

Comment: Assuming that you only have a couple of finders and a few controllers using them then the easiest way is to just manually define your controller services which in turn allows you to use `fos_elastica.finder.articles` or `fos_elastica.finder.fdocentetes`. No need for aliases.  If you have a bunch of finders then you might create a service locator and then have the controller pull the finder from it.  Probably overkill for just a few finders.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution from an existing project.

```yaml
app.service.configuration_service_foo:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\ConfigurationService
    arguments:
      - '@app.config.foo_config'

app.service.configuration_service_bar:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\ConfigurationService
    arguments:
      - '@app.config.bar_config'
```

```php
private ConfigurationService $configServiceFoo;
private ConfigurationService $configServiceBar;

public function __construct(
    ContainerInterface $container,
) {
    $this->configServiceFoo = clone $container->get('app.service.configuration_service_foo');
    $this->configServiceBar = clone $container->get('app.service.configuration_service_bar');
}
```

There may be a better solution.

It is not possible to inject the same object twice via Autowire. Therefore, the ContainerInterface is injected.

Then you have to clone the services. That was 3-4 years ago now. I found out why at that time, but I can't remember now.